# How to update a specific field in Mongodb knowing it's name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have the following code

```
def update_field(db_entity, field_name)
  db_entity_value = db_entity.attributes[field_name]
  if db_entity_value == false
    db_entity.update(field_name: true) # db_entity.update(person_name: true) works!
  end
end
```

it takes two vars: `db_entity` and `field_name`(it's a string value like `"age" or "weight"`). I want to update the value of `field_name`.
I can get its value by using `db_entity.attributes[field_name]` and then I want to set the value to `true` if it was `false`, but I don't know how to update it because `field_name` it's a variable which holds a field name that I want to update. Please, help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def update_field(db_entity, field_name)
  db_entity_value = db_entity.attributes[field_name]
  if db_entity_value == false
    db_entity.update(field_name => true)
  end
end
```

In Ruby when you construct hashes with the hashrocket (`=>`) syntax the keys can be variables.

You can also use [`update_attribute(name, value)`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid%2FPersistable%2FUpdatable:update_attribute).